# Xamarin forms MessagingCenter subscribe is display consoleWrite message while no message

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I use Xamarin forms messaging in 2 contentView.

In my first contentView constructor there is the subscribe Method:

```
public MyWordPage()
{

   MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MyWordPage, MyWords>(this, "UpdateListWords", (sender, arg) =>
{

Console.WriteLine("Message recieved");

});

    
}
```

In my Second contentView there is the sender message in a button method :

```
 void SendMessageButton(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
          MessagingCenter.Send<MyAddWordPage, bool>(this, "UpdateListWords", true);
        }
```

Each contentView s made visible by clicking on a button

```
        bool ViewChange = false;
        void OnChangeViewButton(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ViewChange == false)

            {
                AddWordsView.IsVisible = true;
                MyWordListView.IsVisible = false;
                ViewChange = !ViewChange;
            }
            else
            {
                AddWordsView.IsVisible = false;
                MyWordListView.IsVisible = true;
                ViewChange = !ViewChange;
            }
        }
```

My problem :

The App start with the contentview  MyWordListView which has the subcriber method.

when the app start, I do not know why I get the subsciber message `"Message recieved"` while I did not click the button `SendMessageButton`

What I would like :
I would like to get the message `"Message recieved"` only when I press on the button `SendMessageButton`

Thanks for you help

Comment: the `Send` and `Subscribe` you posted do not even have matching signatures so one should not trigger the other.  Are you sure you don't have another `Send` elsewhere in your code that is doing this, or some other code that is producing the same effect?

Comment: I have uodate it is the same trigger and I am sure about this

Comment: I've used MessagingCenter in dozens of apps and never had a problem with phantom messages.

Comment: Even when the messaging is in constructor ? I do not know why but when I comment the sender message I got nothing when the app start but when I uncomment it,  I got the message when app start

Comment: you are just subscribing in the constructor, nothing should happen until the message is actually received.  If you want to post your solution somewhere I can download it I'll be willing to give it a quick look

Comment: My project is quite big, I am trying to reproduce de problem with a simply solution

Comment: I possible please are you available for a quick call ? I send you a random link please let me know : https://meet.google.com/iwh-tshf-vgy

Comment: Had you tried to add a break point at the `MessagingCenter.Send` to test when the app starts it will call the send method or not?